# homepage link sends to about/about page unable to get home

Tags: html, django, django-urls

I am trying to go back to my home page which is local host. however when trying to link to home using some python script it sends me to my forum page. Even stranger my forum page is at forum/forum/. while using an html href srcipt though it goes back to home. also loads in home. whats going on? im using django 2.2 and python 3.6

```
#tcghome/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('hometemplate.urls')),
    path('forum/', include('hometemplate.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]



#hometemplate/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name ='tcg-home'),
    path('forum/', views.forum, name ='tcg-forum'),
]




#hometemplate/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


posts = [
    {
        'author': 'Pyralis',
        'title': 'Test 1',
        'content': 'test content',
        'date_posted': 'April 19, 2019'
    },
    {
        'author': 'Pyro',
        'title': 'Test 2',
        'content': 'test content how are you',
        'date_posted': 'April 13, 2019'
    },
]


def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': posts
    }
    return render(request, 'hometemplate/home.html', context)
    
def forum(request):
    return render(request, 'hometemplate/forum.html', {'title': 'About'})



#base.html

<a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="{% url 'tcg-home' %}">The Coddiwomple Ginger</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'tcg-forum' %}">Forum</a>

#web source
 <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="/forum/">The Coddiwomple Ginger</a>
 <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
 <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/forum/forum/">Forum</a>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the above project urls.py you are importing include function 2 times which is why you are getting forum/forum/...

amend in ur tcghome/urls.py:--

```
    from django.contrib import admin 
    from django.urls import path, include

    urlpatterns = [
      path('', include('hometemplate.urls')),
       
       path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

in ur HTML do:-----

```
     #base.html

     <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="{% url 'tcg-home' %}">The CoddiwompleGinger</a>
     <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'tcg-home' %}">Home</a>
     <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'tcg-forum' %}">Forum</a>
```

try this, if any problem just let me know .